# Request to the server after clicking "Done" button in combination with pickerView

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry maybe for a too long question, but I brake my head for two days and don't understand why it works how it works. So, I have test application by which learning ability and functions of Swift. The main function of this app shows a value of some crypto coin in some currency.

[image: 1]

And it works properly when I combine it in pickerView. But, I decided to add the following function which must multiply the amount of coin. When I write some number in a numberpad and click to "Done", app show me some mystical numbers.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

And I don't have any ideas why it is. Cause following to the logic of an application, after clicking to "Done", it must do a request to the server and get a value of the coin and multiply them. But it didn't.

[image: 4]

It sends a request only after I begin spin strings in pickerView.

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Will be very thankful, if someone spends time to solve this problem.

```
import UIKit 
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

let baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/"
let coinArray = ["BTC", "ETH", "XRP", "BCH", "LTC"]
let currencyArray = ["EUR", "PLN", "RUB", "USD", "UAH"]
let currencySymbol = ["€", "zł", "₽", "$", "₴"]
var rowForASymbol: Int = 0
var finalURL = ""
var globalCoinValue: Float?

@IBOutlet weak var bitcoinPriceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var valueTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    bitcoinPriceLabel.text = ""

    currencyPicker.delegate = self //the delegate for the picker view
    currencyPicker.dataSource = self //the data source for the picker view
    valueTextField.delegate = self
    self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()

    getBitcoinData(url: baseURL + coinArray[0] + currencyArray[0])

}

//MARK: - Configuration pickerView
//number of columns of data
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 2

}

//number of rows of data
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {

        return coinArray.count

    } else {

        return currencyArray.count

    }

}

//fill the picker row titles with the Strings from currencyArray
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if component == 0 {

        return coinArray[row]

    } else {

        return currencyArray[row]

    }

}

//which row user selected
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var coin = coinArray[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    var currency = currencyArray[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]

    if component == 0 {

        coin = coinArray[row]

    } else {

        rowForASymbol = row
        currency = currencyArray[row]

    }

    finalURL = baseURL + coin + currency

    getBitcoinData(url: finalURL)

}

//MARK: - Networking (Alamofire)
//part that's going to make the HTTP request for the data
func getBitcoinData(url: String) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {

        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

            print("Success! Got the bitcoin data")

            let bitcoinJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            self.updateBitcoinData(json: bitcoinJSON)

        } else {

            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            self.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Connection Issues"

        }

    }

}

//MARK: - JSON Parsing (SwiftyJSON)
//passes the response that we get from bitcoinaverage into something that we can display in our app
func updateBitcoinData(json: JSON) {

    if let coinValue = json["ask"].float {

        if valueTextField.hasText {

            doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue: coinValue)

        } else {

        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "\(coinValue) \(currencySymbol[rowForASymbol])"

        }

    } else {

        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Data unavailable"

    }

}

func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
{
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue:)))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

}

@objc func doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue: Float) {

    if let valueInTextField = valueTextField.text {

        print("valueInTextField: \(valueInTextField)")
        let mulValue = Float(valueInTextField)! * globalCoinValue
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "\(mulValue) \(currencySymbol[rowForASymbol])"
        print("globalCoinValue: \(globalCoinValue)")
        print("mulValue: \(mulValue)")

    }

    self.valueTextField.resignFirstResponder()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getBitcoinData(url: finalURL)` is not fired when you press "Done"

Assuming that `@objc func doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue: Float)` is triggered on button press, you can solve your problem by adding the **following lines:**

```
 var coin = coinArray[currencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
 var currency = currencyArray[currencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
 finalURL = baseURL + coin + currency
 getBitcoinData(url: finalURL)
```

**To `@objc func doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue: Float)` like in a code below**

```
@objc func doneButtonAction(globalCoinValue: Float) {
    if let valueInTextField = valueTextField.text {

        print("valueInTextField: \(valueInTextField)")
        let mulValue = Float(valueInTextField)! * globalCoinValue
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "\(mulValue) \(currencySymbol[rowForASymbol])"
        print("globalCoinValue: \(globalCoinValue)")
        print("mulValue: \(mulValue)")

    }

    self.valueTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    var coin = coinArray[currencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    var currency = currencyArray[currencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    finalURL = baseURL + coin + currency
    getBitcoinData(url: finalURL)

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that, but, for the first time, it again shows those strange numbers and after that begins infinity update (request-response to the server). Maybe you know, how can I achieve only one update?